# How can I fix Malformed entry 51

Tags: 17.04

How can I fix Malformed entry 51 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` so we can try pinpointing which line causes that error?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 has been EOL for several years. Please install a supported release.  This may solve your issue(s).